# I want to login to a web page by passing credentials from java application

Tags: java, ntlm

**I want to login to a web page by passing credentials from java application?**
I am using below code but getting some error:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter("User Name", "user");
client.getParams().setParameter("Password", "password");
GetMethod request = new GetMethod("url");
```

**error:
INFO: No credentials available for NTLM @192.168.224.142:7048**

I have also tried the below code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("user", "password", "ip:port", "http"));
        GetMethod request = new GetMethod("url");
```

error:INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM

suggest a way to login to a web page by passing credentials from java application?.

Comment: Ntlm example https://gist.github.com/virtix/1340440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your user credentials as GET request parameters. The website expects an NTLM-based authentication (the username and password will not be sent to the server).

Use `org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials` to store your username and password.

```
NTCredentials userCredentials = new NTCredentials(userName, password,
                                  System.getProperty("COMPUTERNAME"), domain);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,
                                       AuthScope.ANY_PORT), userCredentials);
HttpClientContext httpClientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
httpClientContext.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().
                      setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```

Feel free to modify the `AuthScope` to your needs.

Comment: what should i use in "domain"

Comment: CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); error:                                                                                  BasicCredentialsProvider cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I don't think that library is required for NTLM

Comment: @Shreyansh Patni: as domain you should use the name of AD domain your user belongs to. It can be `null` if the user does not belong to any domain.

Comment: @cricket_007: which library do you mean?

Comment: Not required, meant completely necessary, as in is there another way... `org.apache.http.auth`...  is some version of the Apache Commons library needed for that? (haven't used it, personally)

Comment: NTCredentials class belongs to Apache HttpClient, which was already used by Shreyansh. As for another way, feel free to describe it in your own answer.

Comment: @Shreyansh Patni: it's kind of unbelievavle, but you have to import classes in order to use them :)
`import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;`?